# Assign Query result in to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @Label AS VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SQL1 AS NVARCHAR(4000) 

SET @SQL1 = 'Select Top 1 AdminID from ERP_AdminLogin'

Exec (@SQL1)

Set @Label = Exec (@SQL1)
```

I want to get the result as `@Lable = 12`

Answer (score 1):

Instead you write like below

```
Select Top 1 @Label=AdminID from ERP_AdminLogin
```

EDIT:

Then simply writing the query in the function, will give your result

```
DECLARE @Label AS VARCHAR(2000)
Select Top 1 @Label=AdminID from ERP_AdminLogin
Set @Label = @Label + 'I' --do some query work here
--finally return the string
select @Label
```

EDIT 1:

If you want to use only inner query, then you can write as below

```
DECLARE @Label AS VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SQL1 AS NVARCHAR(4000) 

SET @SQL1 = 'Select Top 1 @Label=AdminID from ERP_AdminLogin'

exec sp_executesql @SQL1, N'@Label VARCHAR(2000) out', @Label out

select @Label as Result
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply .Since I am writing a function I have to retur a string value.

Comment: I am just giving an Example Bro. Query is not as simple as the given one :)

Comment: Must Return a varchar value; return @Lable

Comment: Writing a big query dynamically

Comment: Sorry. It wont help me. It must be...@sql='select top 1 @lable=AdminId from Adminlogin' then Exec(@sql)

Comment: @Merin, actually executing the query in both cases will result same and you can't assign a variable by writing inner query using "Exec" command.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Bro...This is what I am Exactly looking for. Save my day ;).. Thanks again...let me apply this now

Comment: @ Sai Kalyan..Since I am using this with in a sql function, It is not allowing me to execute :(

Answer (score 0):

See what I tried...

```
create table abc
(
  id int
)

insert into abc values (1);
insert into abc values (2);
insert into abc values (3);
```

//Create function to return desired value

```
create function f_abc() RETURNS varchar(11) 
As
Begin
  DECLARE @Label AS VARCHAR(2000)
  DECLARE @SQL1 AS NVARCHAR(4000) 
  Select Top 1 @Label=id from abc
  return @Label
End
```

//now just call this function

```
select top 1 id, dbo.f_abc() as TempCol  from abc
```

[image: Output]